# Error executing Range.Select

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I don't know what is wrong with this code. it shows an error at Rng.select. When i tested on a separate sheet it worked. Any help?.

```
Sub copyex()
Dim Lastro As Integer
Dim oSht As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range

'make exact copy at S6 for comparasion
 Set oSht = Workbooks("Main.xlsm").Sheets("Work")
 Lastro = oSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

With oSht
Set Rng = oSht.Range("B6:G" & Lastro)
      Rng.Select
      Selection.Copy
      Range("S6").Select
      ActiveSheet.Paste
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

You must Select the Sheet before you Select the Range.

**EDIT#1**:

In your example, you probably do not have to Select the range....try replacing the two lines:

```
Rng.Select
Selection.Copy
```

with the single line:

```
Rng.Copy
```

Comment: ya.. thats why i set my sheet to Workbooks("Main.xlsm").Sheets("Work"). isn't it right?

Comment: You Set the range correctly, but you must Select or Activate the Sheet for you can Select or Activate the range...........I will update my Response.